# gnuplot xticks not equally spaced

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file (d.asc) as follows:

```
0.1  0.5
...  
1    0.34
... 
10   9.4
...
100  45.3
```

In between 0.1 and 1, 1 and 10, 10 and 100 I have 35 values. So that in total in d.asc file I have 109 lines. But I just want x-axis to display these four point values (i.e. 0.1, 1, 10, and 100). To plot it I use the following:

```
set xtics ("0.1" 0.1, "1" 1, "10" 10, "100" 100)
set grid
plot "d.asc" using 1:2 notitle with lines
```

But this gives something weird, it places 1 and 10 very close to 0.1 (kind of overwrites 1 and 10 on top of 0.1). So that I cannot figure out whether it is 0.1, 1, or 10. And places 100 at the end. But what I would expect to see is 0.1, 1, 10, and 100 on x-axis equally spaced from each other. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to be equally spaced from each other, you need to use a `logscale`.

```
set logscale x
```

Or maybe,

```
set logscale x 10
```